# React navigation change background color of material top tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to change border bottom color and background color of material top tabs in react navigation 5

I tried below code but  when I change background color of tabStyle , indicatorStyle border bottom color is not working , but when i remove the tabstyle ,  indicator style is working.

```
 <Nav />
      <tTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
          tabStyle: { backgroundColor: "black" },
          indicatorStyle: {
            borderBottomColor: "#50d3a7",
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
          },
        }}
        initialRouteName="Points"
      >
        <tTab.Screen name="Points" component={pointleftScreen} />
        <tTab.Screen name="Daily Rewards" component={calendarScreen} />
      </tTab.Navigator>
```

I added example here - https://snack.expo.io/@adjmpw/chaneg-borderbottom-and-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `barOptions` prop to customize these stuff

```js
barStyle = {{
  backgroundColor: '#694fad', //Color of your choice
  borderBottomColor: '#50d3a7',
  borderBottomWidth: 2,
}}
```

You will have to use it like this

```
<tTab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Points"
  barStyle={{
    backgroundColor: '#694fad', //Color of your choice
    borderBottomColor: '#50d3a7',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  }}>
  >
  <tTab.Screen name="Points" component={pointleftScreen} />
  <tTab.Screen name="Daily Rewards" component={calendarScreen} />
</tTab.Navigator>
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/chaneg-borderbottom-and-background)

Comment: hi its bottom navigator. , please check on top navigator , I made the example here - https://snack.expo.io/@adjmpw/chaneg-borderbottom-and-background .. when background is changed indicator style is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            }
          }}
```